# LIBGDX "parsing error emitter" with 2 or more emitters

Tags: java, android, libgdx, effect, particles

I have a problem with the use of particle effect of LIBGDX with 2 or more emitters.

After using ParticleEditor to create my .p file, I use it in my code BUT...when I use only 1 emitter it's fine but with more than 1, not fine !  :(

Here is my error code in java console :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing emitter: - Delay -
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:910)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.<init>(ParticleEmitter.java:95)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.loadEmitters(ParticleEffect.java:154)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.load(ParticleEffect.java:138)
    at com.fasgame.fishtrip.android.screens.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:313)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.fasgame.fishtrip.android.screens.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:71)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "- Count -"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.readFloat(ParticleEmitter.java:929)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter$RangedNumericValue.load(ParticleEmitter.java:1062)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:866)
    ... 9 more
```

And here is my particle effect .p file :

```
Blanc
- Delay -
active: false
- Duration - 
lowMin: 3000.0
lowMax: 3000.0
- Count - 
min: 0
max: 200
- Emission - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 250.0
highMax: 250.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Life - 
lowMin: 500.0
lowMax: 500.0
highMin: 500.0
highMax: 500.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 3
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.47058824
scaling2: 0.0
timelineCount: 3
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.51369864
timeline2: 1.0
- Life Offset - 
active: false
- X Offset - 
active: false
- Y Offset - 
active: false
- Spawn Shape - 
shape: point
- Spawn Width - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Spawn Height - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Scale - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 70.0
highMax: 70.0
relative: true
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.0
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Velocity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 30.0
highMax: 300.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Angle - 
active: true
lowMin: 220.0
lowMax: 320.0
highMin: 220.0
highMax: 320.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 0.0
scaling1: 0.98039216
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Rotation - 
active: false
- Wind - 
active: false
- Gravity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Tint - 
colorsCount: 3
colors0: 0.50980395
colors1: 0.7647059
colors2: 0.7921569
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Transparency - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 1.0
highMax: 1.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 4
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 1.0
scaling2: 1.0
scaling3: 1.0
timelineCount: 4
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.36301368
timeline2: 0.6164383
timeline3: 1.0
- Options - 
attached: false
continuous: true
aligned: false
additive: true
behind: false
premultipliedAlpha: false
pre_particle.png

Bleu
- Delay -
active: false
- Duration - 
lowMin: 3000.0
lowMax: 3000.0
- Count - 
min: 0
max: 200
- Emission - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 250.0
highMax: 250.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Life - 
lowMin: 500.0
lowMax: 500.0
highMin: 500.0
highMax: 500.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 3
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.47058824
scaling2: 0.0
timelineCount: 3
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.51369864
timeline2: 1.0
- Life Offset - 
active: false
- X Offset - 
active: false
- Y Offset - 
active: false
- Spawn Shape - 
shape: point
- Spawn Width - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Spawn Height - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Scale - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 70.0
highMax: 70.0
relative: true
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.0
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Velocity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 30.0
highMax: 300.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Angle - 
active: true
lowMin: 220.0
lowMax: 320.0
highMin: 220.0
highMax: 320.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 0.0
scaling1: 0.98039216
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Rotation - 
active: false
- Wind - 
active: false
- Gravity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Tint - 
colorsCount: 3
colors0: 0.0
colors1: 0.7254902
colors2: 0.7921569
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Transparency - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 1.0
highMax: 1.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 6
scaling0: 0.0
scaling1: 1.0
scaling2: 1.0
scaling3: 1.0
scaling4: 1.0
scaling5: 0.0
timelineCount: 6
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.047945205
timeline2: 0.34246576
timeline3: 0.6712329
timeline4: 0.94520545
timeline5: 1.0
- Options - 
attached: false
continuous: true
aligned: false
additive: true
behind: false
premultipliedAlpha: false
pre_particle.png

BleuFonce
- Delay -
active: false
- Duration - 
lowMin: 3000.0
lowMax: 3000.0
- Count - 
min: 0
max: 200
- Emission - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 250.0
highMax: 250.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Life - 
lowMin: 500.0
lowMax: 500.0
highMin: 500.0
highMax: 500.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 3
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.47058824
scaling2: 0.0
timelineCount: 3
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.51369864
timeline2: 1.0
- Life Offset - 
active: false
- X Offset - 
active: false
- Y Offset - 
active: false
- Spawn Shape - 
shape: point
- Spawn Width - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Spawn Height - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Scale - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 70.0
highMax: 70.0
relative: true
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.0
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Velocity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 30.0
highMax: 300.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Angle - 
active: true
lowMin: 220.0
lowMax: 320.0
highMin: 220.0
highMax: 320.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 2
scaling0: 0.0
scaling1: 0.98039216
timelineCount: 2
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 1.0
- Rotation - 
active: false
- Wind - 
active: false
- Gravity - 
active: true
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 0.0
highMax: 0.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 1
scaling0: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Tint - 
colorsCount: 3
colors0: 0.0
colors1: 0.7294118
colors2: 1.0
timelineCount: 1
timeline0: 0.0
- Transparency - 
lowMin: 0.0
lowMax: 0.0
highMin: 1.0
highMax: 1.0
relative: false
scalingCount: 4
scaling0: 1.0
scaling1: 0.0
scaling2: 0.0
scaling3: 1.0
timelineCount: 4
timeline0: 0.0
timeline1: 0.001
timeline2: 0.5753425
timeline3: 0.79452056
- Options - 
attached: false
continuous: true
aligned: false
additive: true
behind: false
premultipliedAlpha: false
pre_particle.png
```

For the "- Image Path -" missing it's normal if I let them in it doesn't work even with only 1 emitter

*PS : I've already updated my lib to the last release*

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by opening my particle effect file and deleting the lines that said:

```
- Image Path -
```

Be sure that the build of the particle editor that you are using is the same as the LibGdx in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get this if you use the same ParticleEditor in your tools library (that was the mistake I made).

Try removing `spriteMode: single` and changing `- Image Paths -` to `- Image Path -`.